# Vertical section of viewshed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, viewshed, visibility, spatial-analysis

[image: Visualization of antenna coverage of a TV channel. Source: tvfool.com]

How can someone make this vertical section of a viewshed analysis (e.g. in ArcMap)?

Comment: Do you have 3D Analyst? The specifics of the graphic output are going to vary in terms of what you can do, but for the actual analysis it looks like you want a [Profile Graph from Line of Sight results](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_profile_graph_from_line_of_sight_results/00q80000006p000000/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to 3D Analyst, there is a tool called Line of Sight from which you can directly create a Profile Graph that indicates which sections are visible and not from the observer points. See [Creating a profile graph from line-of-sight results](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_profile_graph_from_line_of_sight_results/00q80000006p000000/) help file for details.

Note the graphic output options are limited and may not allow you exactly replicate your example. Also note that this is independent from an actual Viewshed analysis. Viewshed looks at areas, and a profile or section of this is just a line, so you're more looking at picking a line on the DEM to use for a [line of sight analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_line_of_sight/00q8000000pz000000/). You can of course use the viewshed results for reference.